# React-native-router-flux Update rightButtonImage dynamically

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have my scene defined inside Router tab as follows:

```
<Scene 
         key="latest"
         title="LATEST"
         titleStyle={{flex:0}}
         component={Latest}
         onRight={()=>{}} 
         rightButtonImage={NOTIFICATION_ICON}
         onLeft={()=>{}}
         leftButtonImage={NAV_SEARCH_ICON}
/>
```

With the above code , I can make navigation action from my Latest screen with the following code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
          this.props.navigation.setParams({
               'onRight': this.showNotifications,
               'onLeft': this.showSearch,
         })
  }
```

So, to update the rightButtonImage from Latest screen , I tried to add rightButtonImage inside the setParams() method as:

```
 this.props.navigation.setParams({
      'onRight': this.showNotifications,
      'onLeft': this.showSearch,
      'rightButtonImage': {NOTIFICATION_ICON_ON}
    })
```

So, basically I want to change my notification bell icon , whenever the new notification arrives . But , by adding 'rightButtonImage' in setParams() doesn't work.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try suing `Actions.refresh`

```
componentDidMount() {
  Actions.refresh({
    rightButtonImage : NOTIFICATION_ICON_ON // this should be an Image
  });
}
```

Or you can use `renderRightButton` in `Actions.refresh`

```
componentDidMount() {
  Actions.refresh({
    renderRightButton : XXXX // this should be an React.Component
  });
}
```

Comment: yep i solved using your comment from other part of stack overflow... anyways thanks man you deserve much more.